# Possible to have setuptools extras_require override requirement from install_requires?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Is it possible to have setuptools's `extras_require` override a requirement set in `install_requires`? My guess is no, as `extras_require` is a

> ...[dictionary mapping names of “extras” (optional features of your project)](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords)...

and so since it is "optional", then `install_requires` will always take precedence. I thought I would ask just in case though.

The reason for asking this is the following use case with the following example `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
  ...
  install_requires = [
    'numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.14.0',
    ...
  ],
  extras_require = {
    ...
    'tensorflow':[
       'tensorflow>=1.10.0',
       'numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3',
       'setuptools<=39.1.0',
    ]
  },
  ...
)
```

You have a library that has support multiple backends for computation (e.g., NumPy, TensorFlow, PyTorch) but the default backend installed is just NumPy and then different backends could be installed through different options. TensorFlow has the requirement that

```
tensorflow 1.10.1 has requirement numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3
```

but you don't want to force the restraint of NumPy if the user just wants the NumPy backend. So *ideally*, one would have in `install_requires` just `numpy>=1.14.0` for users that would do

```
pip install .
```

and then for users that wanted TensorFlow they would just use

```
pip install -e .[tensorflow]
```

However, this of course doesn't work, as if `install_requires` just has `numpy>=1.14.0` then the latest PyPI release of NumPy is installed (at this time `1.15.1`) and you get the warning during installation of

```
tensorflow 1.10.1 has requirement numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3, but you'll have numpy 1.15.1 which is incompatible.
```

So is there anyway that I can unrestrict the NumPy release in `install_requires` and then have setuptools check and use the releases specified in `extras_require` if asked for?

For context:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.6
$ pip --version
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
$ easy_install --version
setuptools 40.0.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (Python 3.6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer (after a bit more thought) is that the outcome is desired *is possible*, but *not* by overriding the `install_requires`, but having a requirement in `install_requires` that requires the library desired (so this is pretty hacky). To illustrate using this `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
  ...
  install_requires = [
    'scipy', # scipy requires numpy, and so will get the latest release from PyPI
    ...
  ],
  extras_require = {
    ...
    'tensorflow':[
       'tensorflow>=1.10.0',
       'numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3',
       'setuptools<=39.1.0',
    ]
  },
  ...
)
```

Now

```
$ pip install .
$ pip freeze | grep numpy
numpy==1.15.1
$ pip freeze | grep scipy
scipy==1.1.0
```

and

```
$ pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
$ pip install .[tensorflow]
$ pip freeze | grep numpy
numpy==1.14.5
$ pip freeze | grep scipy
scipy==1.1.0
```